# How to use a html select in MVC .net using Automapper?

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller

client class :

```
public partial class Client
        {

            public Client()
            {
                this.Produits = new List<Produit>();
            }
            public int idClient { get; set; }
            public string nom { get; set; }
            public string prenom { get; set; }
            public string Email { get; set; }
            public int Tel { get; set; }

            public virtual ICollection<Produit> Produits { get; set; }
        }
```

produit class:

```
public partial class Produit
    {


        public int ProduitID { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int Prix { get; set; }


        public Nullable<int> client_id { get; set; }
        public virtual Client client { get; set; }
    }
```

view produit :

```
// POST: /Produit/Create
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ProduitID,Type,Description,Prix")] ProduitDTO produit)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _ProduitService.Add(produit);
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(produit);
        }
```

I want to use a html `<select>` to show client_id at the view !
Relation between classes : one client have many produit 
i want to show ProduitID,Type,Description,Prix and client_id

```
public class ClientDTO
    {
        [Key]
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int idClient { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "champ requis")]
        [MinLength(3, ErrorMessage = "valeur trop courte")]
        [DisplayName("Nom")]
        public string nom { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "champ requis")]
        [MinLength(3, ErrorMessage = "valeur trop courte")]
        [DisplayName("Prénom")]
        public string prenom { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "champ requis")]
        [MinLength(3, ErrorMessage = "valeur trop courte")]
        [DisplayName("Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public int Tel { get; set; }
    }                

public class ProduitDTO
    {
        [Key]
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int ProduitID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "champ requis")]
        [MinLength(3, ErrorMessage = "valeur trop courte")]
        [DisplayName("Type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "champ requis")]
        [MinLength(3, ErrorMessage = "valeur trop courte")]
        [DisplayName("Description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "champ requis")]
        [MinLength(3, ErrorMessage = "valeur trop courte")]
        [DisplayName("Prix")]
        public int Prix { get; set; }


        public Nullable<int> client_id { get; set; }
        public virtual ClientDTO client { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to show a select list (dropdown list) or a table of all produits associated with the client?

Comment: yes, a dropdown list :)

Comment: Are you using Razor views or ASPX pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert your `ICollection<Produit> Produits` to an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`. A great way to do this is by using a simple lambda:

`IEnumerable<SelectListItem> dropdownItems = db.Client.Find(myClientId).Produits.Select(i => new SelectListItem{ Value = i.ProduitId.ToString(), Text = Produit.Description });`

Attach it to your model somehow:

`Model.DropDownItems = dropdownItems;`

And then you can generate a dropdown-list in Razor using

`@Html.DropDownListFor(Model.DropDownItems)`

Voila.